# C++ Self registering factory in library: No types registered in application

Tags: c++, c++17, static-libraries, factory

I modified the factory pattern with self registering types from [this blog post](http://www.nirfriedman.com/2018/04/29/unforgettable-factory/) for my own needs. Instead of strings I use UUIDs (using `boost.uuid`) to register & build my `node` sub-classes.

The `factory` and corresponding `node` and `node_*` subclasses are part of a library. I link against that library (static library) in my client application and then want to use the library's `factory::build()` function to build objects based on the known UUIDs.

The problem I am facing is that everything is working well both as a standalone minimal example (see below) and within my library itself. However, when I use the `factory::build()` function provided by the library in my application I notice that the `factory::m_generators` map is empty and therefore the factory doesn't know how to build any objects.
When I manually create a dummy object first the factory is able to build further instances of the same class. This indicates that the `node` sub-classes never get instantiated and therefore also never get a chance to register themselves at the factory.

How can I solve this problem?

Here's my code ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0d5227ddbe51a3f)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/string_generator.hpp>

class node;

/**
 * @brief The factory class to build @p node items.
 */
class factory
{
public:
    using key_type  = boost::uuids::uuid;
    using key_hash  = boost::hash<key_type>;
    using generator = std::function<std::unique_ptr<node>()>;

    template<typename Derived>
    struct registrar
    {
        registrar(const key_type& key)
        {
            factory::instance().register_generator(key, [](){
                return std::make_unique<Derived>();
            });
        }

        registrar(const std::string& uuid_string)
        {
            try {
                boost::uuids::string_generator gen;
                registrar(gen(uuid_string));
            } catch (...) {
                ;
            }
        }
    };

    static factory& instance() noexcept
    {
        static factory f;
        return f;
    }

    bool register_generator(const key_type& key, generator&& generator)
    {
        auto [it, emplaced] = m_generators.try_emplace(key, std::move(generator));
        return emplaced;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] std::unique_ptr<node> build(const key_type& key) const
    {
        if (const auto& it = m_generators.find(key); it not_eq m_generators.cend())
            return it->second();
        return nullptr;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] std::unique_ptr<node> build(const char* uuid_string) const noexcept
    {
        try {
            boost::uuids::string_generator gen;
            return build(gen(uuid_string));
        } catch (...) {
            return nullptr;
        }
    }

private:
    std::unordered_map<key_type, generator, key_hash> m_generators;

    factory() = default;
    factory(const factory& other) = default;
    factory(factory&& other) = default;
    virtual ~factory() = default;
};


/**
 * @brief The node base class.
 */
struct node
{
    node(const std::string& uuid_string) :
        m_uuid_string(uuid_string)
    {
    }

    [[nodiscard]] const std::string& uuid_string() const noexcept {
        return m_uuid_string;
    }

private:
    std::string m_uuid_string;
};

/**
 * @brief A template for @p node subclasses.
 */
template <class derived>
struct node_template :
    node,
    factory::registrar<derived>
{
    node_template(const std::string& uuid_string) :
        node(uuid_string),
        factory::registrar<derived>(uuid_string)
    {
        (void) registered;
    }

    static bool do_register() {
        std::cout << "node_template::do_register()" << std::endl;
        derived d; // I am not sure if one should in some way force this to not be optimized away.
        return true;
    }

    inline static bool registered = do_register();
};

struct A : node_template<A> {
    A() : node_template("63cb8eeb-b90b-46c7-aaa8-3a349fcba3c5") { }
};

struct B : node_template<B> {
    B() : node_template("1f24abfc-936f-4524-ae3b-cc346335ecbb") { }
};

static void build_and_print(const std::string& uuid_string)
{
    if (auto node = factory::instance().build(uuid_string.c_str()); node)
        std::cout << "node.uuid_string() = " << node->uuid_string() << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Cannot build node object: Unknown UUID." << std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// PROBLEM: If I do not construct these objects, they never register themselves at the factory. ///
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#if 0
    A a;
    B b;
#endif

    // A
    build_and_print("63cb8eeb-b90b-46c7-aaa8-3a349fcba3c5");

    // B
    build_and_print("1f24abfc-936f-4524-ae3b-cc346335ecbb");

    // Unknown UUID
    build_and_print("9b20cc29-c7ca-4796-acb2-6ca6b80fa934");

    return 0;
}
```

This [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59779679/c-library-self-registering-classes-factory-map-empty-in-client-application) of mine is related.

Comment: Self-registration schemes in libraries basically don't work, because the linker tends to discard any part of the library that doesn't appear to be obviously referenced by the main module. Including the static member that triggers the self-registration. There are (implementation-specific) ways to force the linker to link in certain symbols, but that kinda defeats the point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force a static member to be initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420985/how-to-force-a-static-member-to-be-initialized)

Comment: @DavisHerring I feel like I have the forced initialization in form of the `(void) registered;` line in the `node_template` constructor.

Comment: @JoelBodenmann: Yeah, **if** you create an object of that type *before* you rely on the “automatic” initialization it provides…  Isn’t that the point of this question?

Comment: This looks like a module initialization order issue.  Your client is registered and added to the map _before_ the module where the map global variable itself is initialized.  This causes a reset of the map.  In MSVC, use `#pragma init_seg (lib)` in the module the global map is declared, to force  you library global variable to initalize first.  Maybe someone can help with the pragma for other compilers?