# Unforgettable Factory: When is constructor instantiated?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, factory-pattern

I'm implementing the [unforgettable factory](http://www.nirfriedman.com/2018/04/29/unforgettable-factory/).
Everything works fine but one thing: The classes are not registered, sometimes.

I think the crucial part is the `Registrar::registered` member. If it is used, "The really fun part" calls the `registerT` function which registers the class.

In my toy example, the class is not registered unless either

1. the constructor is implemented (in cpp-file or inline). Explicit default constructor and constructor inheritance (*) do not register the class.
2. there is a virtual method in the base class (`Animal`), which is overridden in the registered class *and* implemented in cpp-file. Inline implementation does not work (unlike inline ctor).

Did I make a mistake or did the author miss something? In my real-world application, *some* classes are registered and *some* are not and I cannot spot the difference (all classes satisfy (1.)), that's why I must deepen my understanding.

My question is: **Under which circumstances exactly is `registerT` called**? In other words: When is the constructor of `Registrar` instantiated?
Where should I put the `(void) registered;` such that it is *always* instantiated?

<sup>(*) to make constructor inheritance work, I made the constructors of `Factory` and `Factory<...>::Registrar` public</sup>

Edit: <sup>[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59779679/4248972) pointed me to the [unforgettable factory blog post](http://www.nirfriedman.com/2018/04/29/unforgettable-factory/). *This is not a duplicate*. The author of that question apparently only forgot to add "The really fun part" and the crucial almost-empty-constructor. I didn't forget them. **I want to know why this crucial almost-empty-constructor is not instantiated although it is there.**</sup>

Edit: **The solution** was not to use the proposed pattern. It does not seem to be fit for production code, see [the relevant issue](https://github.com/pasbi/ommpfritt/issues/100).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ Library & Self registering classes: Factory map empty in client application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59779679/c-library-self-registering-classes-factory-map-empty-in-client-application)

Comment: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order

Comment: @JesperJuhl why do you think static init order is a problem? The initialization order is irrelevant or defined by static functions returning a reference to the resource. The whole thing is used after entering `main`.

Comment: @pasbi I'm not saying it is a/the problem. I just provided a link to something that might be the problem. You are searching for solutions/explanations after all, so I just thought I'd provide a *potential* one.

Comment: @n314159 excellent finding. But, the author of that question apparently only forgot to add "The really fun part" and the crucial almost-empty-constructor. I didn't forget them. I want to know why this crucial almost-empty-constructor is not instantiated although it is there.

Comment: @JesperJuhl thanks for your suggestion, but I'm quite sure that's not the problem. I appreciate arguments that prove me wrong.

Comment: They later had another similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59793556/c-self-registering-factory-in-library-no-types-registered-in-application

Comment: @n314159 That seems to be a partial duplicate :/  Let's get more general:  it'd still like to know when the constructor of `Registrar` is instantiated. Especially point (2.) sounds very dubious. Why does it work when I implement the virtual member in another file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **[basic.start.dynamic]/3** A *non-initialization odr-use* is an odr-use (6.2) not caused directly or indirectly by the initialization of a non-local static or thread storage duration variable.
>
> **[basic.start.dynamic]/4** It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a non-local non-inline variable with static storage duration is sequenced before the first statement of main or is deferred. If it is deferred, it strongly happens before any non-initialization odr-use of any non-inline function or non-inline variable defined in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized.

This is what causes this and similar self-registration schemes to fail. There's a translation unit containing definitions of entities that are not referenced elsewhere in the program, but only by the initializer of a static variable defined in that same translation unit. The implementation may choose to defer the initialization of that static variable until anything in its translation unit is odr-used - which is never.

Comment: Why does it work if the virtual and overridden member method is implemented in another file but not if it is inline? In either case, that method is defined in the same translation unit, isn't it?

Comment: The behavior is implementation-defined; I don't know why a particular implementation behaves a certain way. The point I'm trying to make is, the C++ standard doesn't guarantee that self-registration schemes should work, and in practice they often don't in fact work.

Comment: FTR, I should add that I have moved the `(void) registered;` into `~Registrar`. Still implementation-defined, of course. Bottom line: avoid the Unforgettable Factory and register classes manually. Especially as I want a simple and portable solution.