# C++ registration functions called before main()

Tags: c++, c++14

My program looks something like this:

```
map<string, function<void(const MyType&)>> callables;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    string name = GetFromSomewhere();
    auto iter = callables.find(name);
    if (iter != callables.end()) {
        MyType my_thing = GetSomeValue();
        iter->second(my_thing);
    }
}
```

In other words, I have a table of functions, and main is going to do something that produces a lookup key into that table, do the lookup, and if successful, call the function.

Now I could initialise the table in the translation unit where I define the map, but that means each new function that wants to be in that map has to modify the map's TU.  That gets cumbersome.

Better to have a registration function:

```
void RegisterCallable(const string&, function<void(MyType)>);
```

and then any developer who wants to put something in the table just calls `RegisterCallable()`:

```
# In foo.cc:
void NiftyCallable(const MyType& thing) { ... }

RegisterCallable("nifty", NiftyCallable);
```

Past experience with `string` vs `char[]` warns me that I'm asking for pain, but I've not been able to (re)find the specific C++ rule that tells me when those `RegisterCallable()` calls that we'll scatter about the code base will be called (in particular, if they're guaranteed to be called before main executes or if maybe the TU can load on demand later -- and so whether my memory of pain is correct or not for C++14).

Am I misremembering that this will cause pain?
Or is there a better way to do this other than asking for some TU to know about (currently 100 or so) functions that need registering?

Comment: The way to call functions before `main` is via the constructor of static member objects or global objects. However, it is very important that these objects don't depend on one another or on their initialization order otherwise you will run into the [Static Initialization Order Fiasco](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof). Notably, wherever you register your callback needs to be initialized before anything else that makes use of it. One solution to this problem is to use a Meyers' Singleton.

Comment: Self-registration schemes based on constructors of global objects tend to not work, because linkers can and do eliminate variables and functions that don't appear to be used (the C++ standard permits this). I don't believe such a scheme can be made to work reliably within the standard C++; there exist implementation-specific workarounds,

Comment: Is this meant to be a "toy program", or something intended for real-world use? For anything outside a toy program, generally you will be better off trying to design a proper architecture for this rather than having a global map (whether that's global in the unit, a `static` member, or a singleton)

Comment: Based on the identifier names such as `NiftyCallable` you seem to be well aware of nifty/schwartz counters.  Why not simply used that method to ensure registration occurs as/when you want it to?

Comment: Unless nifty is accidental name... and Schwartz is not strong enough

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thats not true (as a whole). Let us be more exact. Static linker only include what is currently required from static libraries when they build the executable (not the same as variable elision by the compiler). Also this is not mentioned in the standard because libraries creation and usage are not covered (so the standard does not allow this, this is a side effect of something that is beyond the scope of the standard).The standard does not allow the elision of variables that do have a side effects, optimizations by the compiler must not change the observable behavior of the code.

Comment: @MartinYork The money quote is this: "**[basic.start.dynamic]/4** It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a non-local non-inline variable with static storage duration is sequenced before the first statement of `main` or is deferred. If it is deferred, it strongly happens before any non-initialization odr-use of any non-inline function or non-inline variable defined in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized." (continuted)

Comment: @MartinYork In a typical self-registration scheme, the only odr-use of objects and functions in a translation unit is in the initializer of a global variable that exists for the sole purpose of performing the registration. The standard permits this initialization to be deferred until right before something in this translation unit is used, but since noting in that translation unit is used outside of that initialization, the initialization may not be performed at all.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I thought that optimization only happens for things that are not in the global namespace. If they are in the global namespace they must be initialized before main.

Comment: @MartinYork Citation needed. Namespaces control name lookup. Global namespace is no different than any other namespace. In any case, a global variable defined in a global namespace is "a non-local non-inline variable with static storage duration"; what reason do you have to believe that this clause doesn't apply to it?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Seems you are correct. Hold I will update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put the table in global scope put it in function scope (still has to be static to make sure that it lives for the length of the application). So you can force the initialization order. Then you solve the problem of initialization order across compilation units.

```
static std::map<std::string, std::function<void(const MyType&)& getCallables() {
     static std::map<std::string, std::function<void(const MyType&)>> callables;
  // ^^^^^^  Static storage duration object.
  //         lives as long as the application.
     return callables;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::string name = GetFromSomewhere();
    auto iter = getCallables().find(name);
    if (iter != getCallables().end()) {
        MyType my_thing = GetSomeValue();
        iter->second(my_thing);
    }
}
```

When calling from any scope to register a new function it calls `getCallables()` which forces initialization. So you avoid the initialization order issue.

```
void RegisterCallable(const std::string& name, std::function<void(MyType)> f)
{
    getCallables()[name] = f;
}
```

Unfortunately, you can not have freestanding function calls directly in a compilation unit in C++ (unlike a lot of interpreted languages).

```
// So this will not work
RegisterCallable("nifty", NiftyCallable);
```

So the way to do this is to declare objects at global scope whose constructor registers the object.

```
struct DoRegisterCallable {
    DoRegisterCallable(std::string const& name, std::function<void(MyType)> f) {
       RegisterCallable(name, f);
    }
};
```

Now in your compilation unit the person adding the function will do:

```
// In foo.cc:
void NiftyCallable(const MyType& thing) { ... }   
DoRegisterCallable niftyCallableRegister("nifty", NiftyCallable);
```

In the comments above IgorTandetnik suggests that `niftyCallableRegister` may not be included in the executable as the compiler may optimize the variable out. This statement is not interlay true but has merit to think about.

If the file foo.cc is compiled into a static library. Then this static library is linked against the executable, then there is a potential that it may not be included. But in normal situations most builds are done with dynamic libraries not static libraries (as static libraries have so many other issues that people have mostly stopped using them) so this is minor concern in normal operations (but is something to think about).

Additionally, it is implementation defined if file scope, static storage duration variables are initialized before main or deferred. This is easily testable via some unit tests as it is a property of the compiler and not undefined behavior (if you are compiler is doing this then you need to check the documentation to see if the behavior can be changed).

My speculation on this language in the standard is to allow delayed loading of shared libraries till after the application starts, but still guarantee that their behavior conforms to the standard. The way this is written, allows an application to dynamically load a shared library and initialize it (make sure file scope static storage duration objects are initialized) after the application main() has started. A corner case and easily tested via unit test.

---

I may decide that it is nice to wrap this in a class for easy usage:

```
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

class MyType
{
};

using Callable = std::function<void(MyType)>;
using CallableMap = std::map<std::string, Callable>;

class Callables
{

    static CallableMap& getCallables()
    {
        static CallableMap  callables;
        return callables;
    }

    public:
        static void registerFunc(std::string name, std::function<void(MyType)>&& f)
        {
            getCallables()[std::move(name)] = std::move(f);
        }
        static void call(std::string const& name, std::function<MyType()>&& getter)
        {
            auto find = getCallables().find(name);
            if (find != getCallables().end()) {
                find->second(getter());
            }
        }
        static void call(std::string const& name, MyType const& value)
        {
            call(name, [&value](){return value;});
        }
};
struct RegisterCallables
{
    RegisterCallables(std::string value, Callable&& f)
    {
        Callables::registerFunc(std::move(value), std::move(f));
    }
};

void echo(MyType v)
{
    std::cout << "Echo\n";
}
RegisterCallables   echoRegister("echo", echo);

int main()
{
    MyType d;
    Callables::call("echo", d);
}
```

Comment: Does "global scope" here just mean "external linkage"?  I.e., a namespace but not an anonymous namespace?  And the compiler isn't allowed to short-circuit and not create `niftyCallableRegister` because maybe there are side effects despite the object not being used?

Comment: It is a fact that linkers can and do discard the whole `foo.cc` (or rather, the object file produced from it) on the grounds that neither `NiftyCallable` nor `niftyCallableRegister` are used by the rest of the program.  As discussed in comments under the question, the C++ standard sanctions this behavior in `*[basic.start.dynamic]/4**; an implementation that never calls the constructor of `niftyCallableRegister` is conforming.

Comment: @jma I was initially incorrect about the above. I have updated with clarification.  Igor Tandetnik has a point that static storage duration objects creation may be deferred till after main when you read the standard. In practice you can test for this to verify what your compler is doing to make sure the scheme works with your compiler.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The statement: `It is a fact that linkers can and do discard the whole foo.cc` is not true. That is not allowed by the standard. Deferral of calling the the constructors is allowed (by the section you quote) but is not something that happens in most compilers. This language is there to allow the dynamic loading of shared libraries. Do not confuse this with what is done by the static linker as that is a different issue and why we have moved away from static linked libraries (as these have so many issues).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik As you say above citation need for allowing the compiler to discard code from foo.cc

Comment: Again, **[basic.start.dynamic]/4** allows the initialization to be deferred until non-initialization odr-use of something in that translation unit. If nothing in that translation unit is ever odr-used, the initialization can be deferred forever. In practice, this latitude granted by the standard is not taken advantage of by the compiler going to the trouble of generating code that runs initialization just in time (no major implementations do that), but by the linker discarding the whole translation unit, initialization and all. See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59919831)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I don't think your interpretation of that clause is correct. It allows for deferal. Which you are correct may cause the code to never be called. **BUT** the compiler can not discard the code unless it can prove that this code will never be executed (as that would break the optimization rule that no change in observable behavior).  Given that you can dynamically invoke function from other translation units using functions from the OS the compiler can not make that determination and thus is not allowed to drop the code (especially since the objects have potential side effects).

Comment: You have to rember that the intention of that clause is to allow dynamic loading of shared libraries after main and still allow the application to be standard compliant.

Comment: Your linked question is no more convincing.

Comment: It's possible that an implementation building a dynamic library on a system where an arbitrary symbol may be accessed at run time by name (as I think is the case on Linux, but not on Windows where only symbols explicitly exported are thus accessible) would not take advantage of this optimization. But now you are talking implementation details. I'm not saying that self-registration schemes will never work because the optimization is always performed - just that they sometimes don't work because implementations may, and in practice sometimes do, take advantage of this optimization.

Comment: In the linked question, a person has experienced this optimization first-hand - their callbacks failed to register under seemingly-random circumstances. If a practical demonstration of the effect is not sufficient to convince you, then I'm not sure what could.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Its not really a practical demonstration as there is no code to actually consider (so its a rumor from an inexperienced engineer) that may have a bunch of other errors in their code that we can't verify because there is no code. The "seemingly random" is rather a red flag that there is something else wrong here. Also your answer only has one upvote so not a stunning recomendation that it is the correct answer.

Comment: Sure there are time when the compiler could take advantage of implementation details to drop code (as you pointed out on windows) and the situation can be countered for this situation on a case by case basis. But the section you quote from the standard is not the part that allows for this optimization (dropping of code from the executable)And this is all easily testable in a set of unit tests to validate that it actually works.

Comment: Igor you claim but have not show that self registration often don't work. I would suggest they don't work because there is some other error (not because of this issue (differed initialization)). The main reason they don't work is that people forget about the initialization order issue (which the above code does not have). Once you have solved that problem, them self registration code works (and in my experience does not fail when done correctly).

Comment: I have not come across a platform where it failed. If you want to provide an example where it does not work we can see if it is deferred initialization or another issue ccausing the issue.

Comment: (Thanks for the good discussion.  I've added logging, anyway, to alert if a registration happens after a  lookup...)

Comment: What is the benefit of the two versions of `call()` instead of just one,
`static void call(std::string const& name, MyType const& value) { auto find = getCallables().find(name); if (find != getCallables().end()) { find->second(value); }  }`

Comment: @jma The version that takes the lambda only gets the `MyType` object if it finds a function to call with that data. Thus if it is expensive to create the data you don't need to do it if there is no function to call.